# How insert arguments in vararg in Timber?

Tags: android, kotlin, timber

I can't insert arguments in vararg

[image]

The official documentation provides an [example](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#unit-returning-functions) that works fine for me:

```
fun foo(vararg strings: String) { /*...*/ }

foo(strings = *arrayOf("a", "b", "c"))
```

But if I try to use similar in the Timber method i get error:

```
val args = arrayOf("a", "b", "c")
Timber.e(e, "check web", *args)
```

Also here is code Timber code:

```
  /** Log an error exception and a message with optional format args. */
  public static void e(Throwable t, @NonNls String message, Object... args) {
    TREE_OF_SOULS.e(t, message, args);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem with smth like this:

```
Timber.e(
    e,
    "Something went wrong %s %s",
    "Provider name: ${connection.name}",
    "id: ${connection.id}"
)
```

It was also necessary to add the following values `%s` for the strings.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Kotlin syntax issue. Timber comes with lint checks. It can tell how many arguments are in your passed string and whether they match the number of arguments you are passing in the vararg, and show an applicable error or warning at compile time.

[See here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber/blob/4fd8e2a09c81931e9c9b004f45aea2937835278c/timber-lint/src/main/java/timber/lint/WrongTimberUsageDetector.java#L167) for the code that checks for this.

Comment: The problem was in the syntax, where I didn't specify values for my strings.

Comment: That's what I was saying. You didn't put arguments in your format String `"check web"`. That's an omission problem, not syntax.